# Why is $x=\frac{2}{3}$ not a local maximum for $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}(x+1)+\log(x^2-x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Since the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}(x+1)+\log(x^2-x)$ is $f'(x)=\frac{3x^2+x-2}{2(x^2-x)}$, $f'(x)\geq 0$ when $x<-1 \vee 0<x\leq \frac{2}{3} \vee x>1$, then I know that $x=-1$ is local maximum, but I don't know why $x=\frac{2}{3}$ is not a local maximum too.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $2/3$ in place of $3/2$? Then the answer is because $2/3$ is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Edited.

Comment: $\log(x^2-x)$ doesn't exist for $x=2/3$ (unless you consider complex numbers, but then it makes no sense to speak of maxima). A point outside of the function's domain cannot be its local maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of Wojowu's comment, $2/3$ is not a local maximum or minimum for $f(x)$ because $2/3$ is *not in the domain* of $f(x)$. In other words, $f(x)$ is not defined at $2/3$, since the argument of the term $\log(x^2 - x)$ would be $(2/3)^2 - 2/3 = 4/9 - 2/3 = -2/9$, which is less than $0$. $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

First, write the derivative as $$f'(x)=\frac32+\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x},$$ noting that this is only valid in the domain of the original function, being $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,+\infty).$ Clearly this does not include $2/3.$

Comment: OP's derivative is simplified version of yours, so why wrong?

Comment: @farruhota You're right. I wouldn't call it simplified though. The form in which I left it makes some of its properties obvious.

Comment: OP found for $x<-1$ the derivative is positive, therefore it is simplified

Comment: @farruhota Oops! I completely ignored the fact that $3/2$ always exceeds the second summand in this case.